# Brew info in Lion is missing characters with postgres

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion, homebrew

I have a fresh install of Lion that I just installed brew on. However, after it seemed to install, there are missing characters in the brew info. Furthermore, when I check for postgres versions, it only lists a single version.

My other Mac systems have worked just fine so I'm at a loss here.

I've attached a picture of what I'm talking about below.

[image: http://imgur.com/mEyEUAG]

Answer (score 0):

`postgres` is aliased to `postgresql`, and if you want to install a different `postgresql` version then they're `postgres8`, `postgres9`, `postgres91`. postgresql is `9.2`. brew versions on the alias is not going to return the other versions as they're not supplied. If you want to find all the available versions of postgres, then you should use `brew search postgres`.

The text problem looks like buggy indentation. Unless it actually impacts something then I would not worry about it.

To debug this properly, you need to be asking the correct questions:

- Were the other systems that it worked on using the same version of Mac OS X?
- Are they running the same version of brew (what does brew --version report)?
- did they have the same homebrew data? i.e. all up to date?
- Did you test it with the same brew version and data on another system?

At a guess, it looks like this:

```
commit 35d607cc2fd962af6323fce6aab3f8f5c3fd0946
Author: Adam Vandenberg <flangy@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 6 09:21:11 2013 -0700

    postgres: fix nesting
```

fixes the indentation problem (although that's just a guesstimate). So the issue may not exist on the latest brew formula.

Comment: All my systems, including this one, run Lion and are on brew 0.9.4 and freshly updated. Furthermore, when I check postgres version on my other systems, it outputs a list of versions down to 8.4.4. The one difference I can think of between my systems is the version of postgresql installed. One of my systems is on 9.1.3, another is on 9.2.3

Comment: brew list lists the *installed* versions, rather than the available versions. it sounds like you've installed other versions on those systems.